# Python Pandas: How to groupby and compare columns

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, comparison

Here is my datafarme 'df':

```
match           name                   group  
adamant         Adamant Home Network   86   
adamant         ADAMANT, Ltd.          86   
adamant bild    TOV Adamant-Bild       86   
360works        360WORKS               94   
360works        360works.com           94
```

Per group number I want to compare the names one by one and see if they are matched to a same word from the 'match' column.

So desired output will be counts:

```
 If they match we count it as 'TP' and if not we count it as 'FN'.
```

I had an idea of counting number of match words per group number but that would not help completely with what I want:

```
df.groupby(group).count()
```

Does any body have an idea how to do it?

Comment: Could you post desired output, thanks

Comment: could you explain what you consider to be a match, are you just checking if the words in 'match' is present in 'name'?

Comment: @EdChum match means that when we compare the words from the same group number pairwise, they have a same word in their 'match' column

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood well your question, this should do the work:

```
import re
import pandas


df = pandas.DataFrame([['adamant', 'Adamant Home Network', 86], ['adamant', 'ADAMANT, Ltd.', 86],
                       ['adamant bild', "TOV Adamant-Bild", 86], ['360works', '360WORKS', 94],
                       ['360works ', "360works.com ", 94]], columns=['match', 'name', 'group'])


def my_function(group):
    for i, row in group.iterrows():
        if ''.join(re.findall("[a-zA-Z]+", row['match'])).lower() not in ''.join(
                re.findall("[a-zA-Z]+", row['name'])).lower():
            # parsing the names in each columns and looking for an inclusion
            # if one of the inclusion fails, we return 'FN'
            return 'FN'
    # if all inclusions succeed, we return 'TP'
    return 'TP'


res_series = df.groupby('group').apply(my_function)
res_series.name = 'count'
res_df = res_series.reset_index()
print res_df
```

This will give you this DataFrame:

```
     group     count
1    86        'TP'
2    94        'TP'
```

Comment: @user3478208 would this code work in Pandas? cause  don't we have to have 'def' for functions?

Comment: I am receiving this error : AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'iterrows'

Comment: Thanks. I am still receiving this error.TypeError: expected string or buffer

Comment: If you copy all my code and paste it on your python editor, it works and give the output I state.

Comment: Did you try using your Dataset or the one I give in the example? Because I am sure your dataset is distinct from what you are showing us if you can't run my code.

Answer (score 1):

This function will compare name and match columns by row, for each supplied group:

```
def apply_func(df):
    x = df['name'] == df['match']
    return x.map({False:'FIN', True:'TP'})

In [683]: temp.join(temp.groupby('group').apply(apply_func).reset_index(), rsuffix='_1', how='left')
Out[683]: 
           match                  name  group  group_1  level_1    0
0        adamant  Adamant Home Network     86       86        0  FIN
1        adamant         ADAMANT, Ltd.     86       86        1  FIN
2  adamant bild       TOV Adamant-Bild     86       86        2  FIN
3       360works              360WORKS     94       94        3  FIN
4       360works          360works.com     94       94        4  FIN
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. But that is not what I want. because I want to compare rows of names with each other per group number so in this case for instance I want to compare 360works.com and 360works to see if they have same 'match'

Comment: Inside the group, do you want to match on a row basis or a column basis ?

Comment: row basis. so to match three entities of group 86 two by two in  terms of their 'match' word